# DataGridView displaying superfluous column on the left - how to get rid of it?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

My DataGridView displays a "0" column with a delta in the first row and a * in the second. I don't want these. They take up too much space. Is there a way to get them to go away?

I don't think the code is pertinent in this case, but to humor y'all, here it is:

```
private void PopulateLanguageAndPrimary() {
    string query;
    OracleDataAdapter da;
    OracleDataTable dt;
    OracleCommand oc;

    try {
        oracleConnectionMainForm.Open();
        query = "select position, coach from players where team = :team";
        da = new OracleDataAdapter();
        oc = new OracleCommand(query, oracleConnectionMainForm);
        oc.Parameters.Add("team", greenBayPackers);
        da.SelectCommand = oc;
        dt = new OracleDataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.DataSource = dt;
    } catch (OracleException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } finally {
        oracleConnectionMainForm.Close();
    }
}
```

- added scream shot at: http://warbler.posterous.com/heres-the-unwanted-bling-on-the-datagridview#

Comment: You need to provide more details, some code, etc if you want to get some help. We can't see your datagridview so we would be guessing as the problem. Even a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: Do you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`?

Comment: @CAbbott: DataGridView for Winforms has no such property.

Comment: @bluefeet: How or where do I post a screenshot? The code behind this has nothing to do with the appearance of the grid - it's just code to query the DB and then hook up the DataAdapter, DataTable, OracleConnection, OracleCommand, to one another and to this DataGridView. I simply want two columns to display - the two I'm fetching via the query, nothing extra (which it apparently does by default).

Comment: @ClayShannon you say you are seeing extra columns, show us. I have never seen extra columns show up in datagridviews.

Comment: @ClayShannon: DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx

Comment: More importantly, what is your datasource?

Comment: @dwerner - I don't see why my datasource matters; I am getting data, I'm just getting some "bling" that Microsoft is supplying that I don't want; however, it's an OracleDattaTable, which fills an OracleDataAdapter (devArt dotConnect for Oracle components).

Comment: @John: When I set AutoGenerateColumns to false, I get no data displayed at all. I've tried setting Locked to True, Multiselect to False, Readonly to True, SelectionMode to FullRowSelect, etc., but that dad-blamed worthless son of a seasnake column continues to stare at me in mirthful derision at every turn.

Is there a way to set column0.Width = 0?

Comment: The contents of your DataSource determine the columns generated, if it is set to AutoGenerateColumns==true. Otherwise, you could have a bad column definition. Could you post a screenshot maybe?

Comment: @dwerner: post a screen shot where?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91716/how-to-upload-screenshots

Comment: Well, not surprisingly, that irritating column is really a pseudocolumn, for when I do this:

dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns.Remove(dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns[0]);

...it removes the first column with valuable data in it (not the "bling" column).

And just for grimaces, I tried this:

     dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns.Remove(dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns[-1]);

...but predictably, it blew up in my face with a rather loud and cacaphonous racket.

Comment: OK, I'll post the code above, although I'm 99.42% sure it's got nothing to do with the superfluous bling.

Comment: OK, I temporarily added a scream shot to: http://warbler.posterous.com/heres-the-unwanted-bling-on-the-datagridview#

Comment: My link above was to illustrate that you can post screenshots here on SO!

Comment: Well, not surprisingly, that irritating column is really a pseudocolumn, for when I do this:

dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns.Remove(dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns[0]);

...it removes the first column with valuable data in it (not the "bling" column).

And just for grimaces, I tried this:

     dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns.Remove(dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.Columns[-1]);

...but predictably, it blew up in my face with a rather loud and cacaphonous racket.

Comment: @dwerner: That link doesn't seem to really help, as I don't see any such toolbar; maybe I need more points before it's visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting `dataGridViewLanguageAndPrimary.AllowUserToAddRow` to false. This will remove the *. Then set `RowHeadersVisible` to false, hiding the superfluous column.

Comment: That got rid of the "*" column; we're on the right track. There must be another "AllowUserToX" property to 86 the delta.

Comment: The row with '0' you mean? I'm pretty sure that's from an empty DataTable/DataSet, so if you try not assigning the DataSource, or check the DataTable.Rows property for .Count (or Length, I forget)

Comment: I changed all of the "AllowUserToX" properties to false, but I still have the superfluous column with the delta.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the column (which is not really a column, as "Language" is column 0. I can drag it out of the way / cover it over at run-time. I wonder if there's a way to do that in code, or set its width to 0?

Comment: That's the ticket (RowHeadersVisible = false)!